# Request sql using a given month postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to select count of rows from my table where the month is 05

```
select count(*) from planificationsupervision where date is '%-05-%'
```

date is a column with type date, my database is postgres, i obtain error in the syntax

thank u for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM planificationsupervision 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = 5;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aed18/1/0)**</kbd>